# Rails: Link changes one attribute and then goes back

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Rails newbie here.

I have a list of `items` which can have a `status` represented by an integer (right now its just 1=active 0=inactive).

What I want is next to each `item` a link to change the `status` of that item.  So it might look like this:

> A nice item - Enable
>
> Another pretty item - Disable

I can't think of how to make the link work.  I just want a user to click the link and then the page refreshes and the `item` get updated.

This doesn't work:

```
<%= link_to "Enable", :controller => "items", :action => "update", :status => 1 %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the default rails controller implemented, this

```
<%= link_to "Enable", :controller => "items", :action => "update", :status => 1 %>
```

is not working because in the update action rails calls

```
@item.update_attributes(params[:item])
```

and the status is going to the controller as

```
params[:status]
```

Beside that, to call update the method must be PUT.

Try changing the link to something like:

```
<%= link_to "Enable", :controller => "items", :action => "update", :method => :put :item => {:status => 1} %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like

```
# view
<% @items.each do |item| %>
   # ...
   link = link_to_remote((item.active? "Disable" : "Enable"), :url => {
      :controller => "items", :action => "swap_status", :id => item.id
   })
   <%= item.name %> - <%= link %>
<% end %>


# item model
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
   # ...    
   def active?
      self.status == 1
   end
end

# items controller
class ItemsController < ApplicationController
   # ...
   def swap_status
      item = Item.find(params[:id])
      new_status = item.active? ? 0 : 1
      item.update_attribute(:status, new_status)
      # and then you have to update the link in the view,
      #    which I don't know exactly how to do yet.
   end
end
```

I know it's incomplete... but I hope it helps you somehow :]

Comment: I think he should use the default update action that rest provides to update a field of his model. Creating a new action to do that is highly unrecommended.